# How to integrate Juggernaut chat server (Powered by ruby on rails) with iPhone/Android app for real time chat?

Tags: iphone, android, ruby-on-rails, chat, juggernaut

*Preview*:

I am using [juggernaut chat server](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut).I am having redis and juggernaut server running on machine. I am able to do chats within my local network on vaious web browsers. Everything is working smoothly. As juggernaut is a server driven chat server so i am quite sure about the scalability thing. Now here is the thing:--

*Whats the problem:*

I want to have a **iphone native app** too where user can login and chat with his friends. **Now the thing i want to know is how do I push on iphone app, cause for juggernaut client registration a javascript code is needed.** Something like this:

```
          var jug = new Juggernaut;
      jug.subscribe("channel1", function(data){
        alert(data);
      });
```

Basically how do i push new notifications to Iphone chat window. I don't know much about iphone as I am web developer. Still from google search etc I came to know some possible ( may be) ways:-

- **We can embed a url in iphone window. Is this a good approach?**
- **Other thing we can do is using [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/) kind of services we can do push notifications. Will push notification works for chat? I don't know about that even.**
- **Third option can be polling. Iphone chat client keeps on hitting my rails app for new notifications. But i think this will be a very bad approach.**

***What are the other possible solutions?***

Can any iPhone/Android developer guide me what should i do. I will eventually hire a Iphone developer to do all the coding part. But I want to have a big picture in my mind so that I can provide a complete docs of all the things, and have a clear picture how I want to discuss things with him before writing down the code.

**PS:** I am looking for a solution which works for android/nokia devices too. Cause later on I will be developing an application for that too. *Basically it will be good to have a same solution.* if not then compatibility factor should be there atleast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this library: https://github.com/fpotter/juggernaut-cocoa

It's really easy to use.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the feedback. I'm fairly new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is WebSocket support in MobileSafari on 4.2 ([source](http://jimbergman.net/websockets-supported-in-ios-4-2/)).  You could probably write up a client that uses an embedded `UIWebView` to marshall the events to/from the Juggernaut server and deliver them to your app via `shouldOpenURL` and custom handlers.

You might also look at [libPusher](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher) by Luke Redpath for interacting with push communication via the [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) web service.

Comment: Pusher seems too costly for me thats y I am setting up my own chat server on amazon. Juggernaut seems best option for it. All I need is to push chats on native Iphone/Android app without using pusher etc.

Comment: version 4.2.. Its kinda latest one.. Then how facebook chat is working on iPhone on previous version of iOS?

Comment: It could be polling, I'm not sure.  Are you convinced they're using Juggernaut and/or WebSockets?